# React Error: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a beginner at React. I wrote this code and got an Error

```
import { DoItem } from '../MyComponents/DoItem'
export const ToDo = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <h3 className="text-center">To Do List</h3>
            {props.todos.map((todo) => { 
                return ( 
                    <>
                        <DoItem const todo={todo} onDelete = {props.onDelete} /> 
                        <hr />
                    </>
                    ) 
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Here's the error **Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.**

I looked online and found that I have to use a key.
I inserted the key
`<DoItem const todo={todo} key={todo.nos} onDelete = {props.onDelete} />`

But the error still didn't go after I reload the page.

Comment: Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. You should use key={i}, in <DoItem key={i} />

Comment: @SifatAmin React warns against using `map`'s index as a key which is why I'm assuming the OP is using the number from the object.

Comment: I as in Id or some unique identity. @Andy

Comment: Hi Nisarg!
As you know, I upvoted you. Would you like to upvote my answer, kindly?
Thanks, Oscar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add a unique key to every item

```
{props.todos.map((todo, index) => { 
                return ( 
                    <div key={index}>
                        <DoItem const todo={todo} onDelete = {props.onDelete} /> 
                        <hr />
                    </div>
                    ) 
            })}
```

Please have a try and let me know if it works or not.

Comment: Hey! This worked out! Can you explain what was the issue with my method of key?

Comment: Sure, your map will generates serveral <> </> elements into your container without any keys. This will make an error. Does it clear for you?

Comment: The key needed to be on the first element, and since you were using a fragment React was throwing an error because it's not actually an element.

Comment: No, actually I was following the steps mentioned on a youtube video and that guy had the same problem as mine and it resolved by what I did. But, I was still getting the error

Comment: Okay, so if I had used <div> instead of empty <> I wouldn't have gotten an error for my method?

Comment: If so, `todo.nos` will not a unique key. But index is always unique. Using index as a key is a good solution.

Comment: Okay @OscarCardosoGarcia but why did the problem get resolved for that Youtuber when I did everything step by step?

Comment: I guess in the video `todo.nos` could be unique. You can check the `todo.nos` value with console.log.

Comment: No it wasn't unique. He said we could use anything either nos or sno and I did the console and got undefined

Comment: The problem is you have serveral <hr /> tags in the container. This is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
import { DoItem } from '../MyComponents/DoItem'
export const ToDo = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <h3 className="text-center">To Do List</h3>
            {props.todos.map((todo, i) => { 
                return ( 
                    <key={i}>
                        <DoItem const todo={todo} onDelete = {props.onDelete} /> 
                        <hr />
                    </>
                    ) 
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Yes, it does now!! But I was following the steps mentioned on a youtube video and that guy had the same problem as mine and it got resolved by what I did. But, I was still getting the error and he moved on.

Comment: Well, actually this is not a fatal error and everything will work fine even with this error. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, you should add a key prop to anytime you're rendering an Array.

```
import { DoItem } from '../MyComponents/DoItem'
export const ToDo = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <h3 className="text-center">To Do List</h3>
            {props.todos.map((todo,index) => { 
                return ( 
                    <div key={index | the id of the todo}>
                        <DoItem const todo={todo} onDelete = {props.onDelete} /> 
                        <hr />
                    </div>
                    ) 
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
```